# Define sync directory on bitbucket pipeline

Tags: git, ftp, bitbucket-pipelines, git-ftp

I am using folder structure for local vagrant development,

-bin
-htdocs
-resources
-vagrant

those folders are on git
but I want to clone only **htdocs** folder content on server using `git ftp push`

How to define clone directory on **bitbucket pipelines**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the following documentation on
https://www.mankier.com/1/git-ftp#Defaults

There is need to set **syncroot** in git config

Before executing of command `git ftp <init|push>`
git should be configured like on this example

```
$ git config git-ftp.user john
$ git config git-ftp.url ftp.example.com
$ git config git-ftp.password secr3t
$ git config git-ftp.syncroot path/dir
```

or use one line command

```
$ git config git-ftp.<(url|user|password|syncroot|cacert)> <value>
```